# SQL OrderBy When using an In() query

Tags: sql-server

Example query

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID in (5,3,4)
```

How do I adjust this query so that the order of the returned entries follows the input of the ID's (IE, 5 first, 3 second, 4 third).

Edit - To be clear the ID's a dynamically generated list that is in the right order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best bet is going to be to split the list into a temp table.

I'm using Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8k.  You can find the code [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).  Note it includes an ItemNumber column that is the values in order.

```
DECLARE @DelimString varchar(50) = '4,5,3'

SELECT * INTO #DelimList FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8k(@DelimString,',')

SELECT Table.*
FROM Table
JOIN #DelimList
    ON Table.Id = #DelimList.Item
ORDER BY #DelimList.ItemNumber
```

This has the added benefit of being faster for large numbers of values in the delimited list.

Answer (score 4):

If you're generating that list, then try generating something like this instead:

```
JOIN (VALUES (5,1), (3,2), (4,3)) AS l(val, orderby)
  ON l.val = t.ID
ORDER BY l.orderby;
```

Or better still: generate an insert values statement for an indexed table or variable that avoids a sort for the order by clause. There will still likely be a sort for the insert of rows to the table or variable, but that will usually be cheaper/less likely to spill than in the main query.

Comment: @LiamB - potentially, but Kenneth's answer is good too. I added it because it's a simpler answer.

Answer (score -3):

Since the IDs are out of order (not DESCENDING or ASCENDING) I'd use UNION.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = 5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = 4
```

As a side note, using `SELECT *` in a UNION query isn't a good idea (and the rest of the time, it's debatable) - use the actual column names instead.

EDIT: It's been pointed out this won't necessarily work; and especially not with dynamic ID lists, like the edited question specifies.

Comment: Putting them in separate queries like this won't help because it is in a single query you still can't guarantee the order without an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Downvoted. While this technique may *happen* to return the rows in the desired order there is no guarantee unless an ORDER BY clause is coded.